# Why Bottom line indented a bit to the right

Tags: html, css

No padding, no margin still why the bottom line shifted a bit to the right side.
I have tested by increasing and decreasing the ***word-spacing*** and ***letter-spacing*** but still the same.

I can get both lines aligned by adding a bit of ***padding-left*** to the first line. But why is this happening.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

html {
  font-size: 6px;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-primary {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  
}

.heading-primary-main {
  display: block;
  font-size: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.heading-primary-sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  word-spacing: 1.2rem;    /*====================*/
  letter-spacing: 1.55rem; /*===================*/
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="text-box">
    <div class="heading-primary">
      <span class="heading-primary-main">OUTDOORS</span>
      <span class="heading-primary-sub">Is where life happens</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you are centring the text

Comment: @TemaniAfif that ***center*** is for both lines. Its on the ***.text-box*** why is working like this. OK assume second line is getting centered, then why not first line getting centered.

Comment: the first line is wider and is the one defining the width so there is nothing to center there that's why it affect only the second line

Comment: Run the snippet, there is so much space after last letter **S**

Comment: that space is a part of the text, inspect the element and you will notice this

Comment: @TemaniAfif thats what i want to know from where that space is coming. Both lines are inside ***<span>*** and i am getting that extra space for no reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter-spacing causes the top row to be 100% width of the available space, so there is no space to center within.

However, the reason that the text looks left aligned is because letter-spacing is added to the right side of a letter, not equal on both sides.

There are a few solutions:
- Add negative margin on the left
- Add left padding
- Text-indent may also be useful

Comment: I want to center both lines. If first line centered i have no issue. But its not happening. that ***text-align:center*** is on ***.text-box*** class. why it is behaving like this

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. This behaviour is caused by the letter-spacing is added to the right of each letter, instead of equal on both sides:
https://adamschwartz.co/magic-of-css/potions/letter-spacing/